CPQ: Can a Product be set up to be sold exclusively as part of a bundle?
Using CPQ, Is it possible to set up a Product so that it can be sold as part of a bundle while preventing it from being sold as a stand-alone item?
For example, I have product A which has Product B and C as Product Options. I don't want B and C to appear as available products in the Quote Line Editor, but I do want them to appear as Add-On features as part of a bundle for product A.

Found the answer: Yes, this is possible. By checking the "Component" checkbox on the product, it makes that product not appear in the quote line editor but available within product bundles via Product Option records.
